# React Native floating animation

Tags: react-native, android-animation

How can I achieve the animation similar to codepen pen link as follows
https://codepen.io/whusterj/pres/bdYKop

HTML code

```
<div class="floating"
     style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background: rgb(200,200,200);">
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.floating {  
    animation-name: floating;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 30px;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

@keyframes floating {
    from { transform: translate(0,  0px); }
    65%  { transform: translate(0, 15px); }
    to   { transform: translate(0, -0px); }    
}
```

in React Native ( Android App )

I tried exploring with react-native [Animated](https://codepen.io/whusterj/pres/bdYKop) but no luck

can anyone show me the code to implement the same

That will be really helpful

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark as answer if this helps!

```
import React from 'react';
import {Animated, TextInput, View, Easing} from 'react-native';

export default class Main extends React.Component {

    state = {verticalVal: new Animated.Value(0)}

    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(this.state.verticalVal, {toValue: 50, duration: 1000, easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.quad)}).start();
        this.state.verticalVal.addListener(({value}) => {
            if (value == 50) {
                Animated.timing(this.state.verticalVal, {toValue: 0, duration: 1000, easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.quad)}).start();
            }
            else if (value == 0) {
                Animated.timing(this.state.verticalVal, {toValue: 50, duration: 1000, easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.quad)}).start();
            };
        })
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <Animated.View style = {{backgroundColor: "#0787d7", height: 100, width: 100, transform: [{translateY: this.state.verticalVal}]}}></Animated.View>
        );
    };
};
```

Try this out! You can change the easing curve!
This works however. Hope it helped you.

Comment: it's really cool, is there any tutorial, blog or article where I can learn the react-native Animated

Comment: I see. As far as I remember I also wanted some kind of tutorial for that when I was learning. But I ended up reading the documentation. I can recommend the same to you. Facebook has made good documentation about it.